# auto-hide dock does not show up

Tags: dock, 21.04, autohide

Since I upgraded to 21.04, my auto-hide dock (at the left of the screen) remains hidden until I switch its position to the right and back to the left. After that it works as expected (i.e. it appears when the mouse goes to the left edge of the screen).

EDIT after @vanadium's comment:

Normally the auto-hidden dock should become visible in its chosen position (left, below or right) when the mouse cursor comes to this edge of the screen. But for me, after starting up the computer and logging in, this does not work. The dock does not appear.

I have to change anything in the dock settings (e.g. change the location or switching the auto-hide feature off and on) to make it work correctly for the rest of the session.

PS: Today it worked from the beginning without any intervention. A mysterious case of self-healing?

PPS (one day after the PS): It happened again today. Perhaps a question of timing during startup? How can I delay the start of the dock?

Comment: Thanks for the information. What is now the actual problem? That it keeps not working when you log out then back in, or after you restart the computer? What is the question you are asking? Please clarify.

Comment: @vanadium: I added further details, but today for once it worked!

Comment: Do you also have Dash to Panel installed in your system along with dash to dock?

Comment: @1nfern0 
$ gnome-extensions list
ding@rastersoft.com
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has disappeared when I changed my login from wayland to gnome (persistent option on the login screen).

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting called as pressure in the dock which regulates with how much speed you should move the cursor towards the dock for it to show from auto hide. You can either regulate it or remove pressure settings entirely using dconf editor. First install dconf editor with

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Go to “org > gnome > shell> extensions > dash-to-dock”, There scroll down to the nearly the bottom. There are two settings
**Pressure threshold** or **Require-pressure-to-show**. You can turn off pressure to show or adjust the threshold, restart and see it take effect

Answer (score -1):

This is my version of this issue.

When the application's window is "full screen", there seems to be a "speed-related" issue detecting that the cursor is against the screen edge where the "dock" is located.  If the cursor icon meets the screen edge slowly, the dock does not appear.  If the cursor icon is "crashed" into the screen edge, the dock will appear.  However, when the dock appears, it may be: (1) "bouncing" and will disappear when the cursor is moved in any meaningful way; or (2) the dock will be stable and can be used as desired.  The author of this feature may have had two objectives.  First, if the cursor icon accidentally touches the screen edge, the author wanted the dock to remain hidden.  For me, this is a good feature.  I applaud the effort.  Second, if the cursor icon is "slammed into" the screen edge in a meaningful way, the user is indicating the dock should appear.  This result seems to occur - most of the time.  Appearing every time would be even better.  However, the bouncing dock has me getting sea sick.  There must be confusion inside the algorithm deciding if the "cursor" meets the "screen edge" slowly or quickly.

A not too scientific observation:  Success making the dock appear is better if the cursor icon impacts the "screen edge/dock-area" where there are no dock icons.

Comment: This is not the cause of my problem, as it happens also with no application started. Right after login the dock does not appear when I move the mouse to the edge.

Comment: This also isn't an answer.